# Sequence of only time (no dates) in r

Tags: r, chron

I am trying to make a sequence that only consists of times with one hour interval, without dates. It should look like this:

```
"00:00:00" "1:00:00" "2:00:00" "3:00:00"
```

I know that this code works:

```
dat <- seq(
  from=as.POSIXct("00:00:00","%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC"),
  to=as.POSIXct("23:00:00", "%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC"),
  by="hour"
)
```

Which gives

```
[1] "2018-04-10 00:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 01:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 02:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 03:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 04:00:00 UTC"
 [6] "2018-04-10 05:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 06:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 07:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 08:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 09:00:00 UTC"
[11] "2018-04-10 10:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 11:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 12:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 13:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 14:00:00 UTC"
[16] "2018-04-10 15:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 16:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 17:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 18:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 19:00:00 UTC"
[21] "2018-04-10 20:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 21:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 22:00:00 UTC" "2018-04-10 23:00:00 UTC"
```

But that is not what I want. Therefore I tried

```
library(chron)
seq(from = times("00:00:00"), to =times("23:00:00"), by="hour")
```

which gives an error

```
Error in convert.times(times., fmt) : format h:m:s may be incorrect
In addition: Warning message:
In unpaste(times, sep = fmt$sep, fnames = fmt$periods, nfields = 3) :
  wrong number of fields in entry(ies) 1
```

I am stuck now, so I hope somebody can help me with this. 
Of course I could just type it out, but I want to have a clean solution.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with your sample data please?

Comment: I assumed this was not necessary as I only needed help to create the vector. I think it will become unnecessarily complex if I would explain what I need it for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using package chron which provides a `times` class:

```
library(chron)
times("00:00:00") + (0:23)/24
#[1] 00:00:00 01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00 04:00:00 05:00:00 06:00:00 07:00:00 08:00:00 09:00:00 10:00:00 11:00:00 12:00:00 13:00:00 14:00:00
#[16] 15:00:00 16:00:00 17:00:00 18:00:00 19:00:00 20:00:00 21:00:00 22:00:00 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strftime()` to extract values in any format to character:

```
dat <- seq(
  from=as.POSIXct("00:00:00","%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC"),
  to=as.POSIXct("23:00:00", "%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC"),
  by="hour"
)
strftime(dat, format="%H:%M:%S")
#"02:00:00" "03:00:00" "04:00:00" "05:00:00" "06:00:00" "07:00:00"
#"08:00:00" "09:00:00" "10:00:00" "11:00:00" "12:00:00" "13:00:00"
#"14:00:00" "15:00:00" "16:00:00" "17:00:00" "18:00:00" "19:00:00" 
#"20:00:00" "21:00:00" "22:00:00" "23:00:00" "00:00:00" "01:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `POSIXct` class,
to extract only the hour, minutes and seconds you just need to do:

```
as.character(format(from, "%H:%M:%S"))
as.character(format(to, "%H:%M:%S"))
```